# when i shrink the window to mobile size , the humburger doesn't show .pllz help to make this responsive header for my project

Tags: html, css, web

when i shrink the window to mobile size , the humburger doesn't show .pllz help to make this responsive header for my project .

```
<div id="menu-bar" class="fas fa-bars"></div>
<div class="container-ring">
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <a href="#" class="logo"><span>T</span>ravel</a>
</div>


<nav class="navbar">
    <a href="index.html">home</a>
    <a href="about.html">about</a>
    <a href="Tour.html">tour</a>
    <a href="Blog.html">blog</a>
    <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
</nav>

<div class="icons">
    <i class="fas fa-search" id="search-btn"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-user" id="login-btn"></i>
</div>

<form action="#" class="search-bar-container">
    <input type="search" id="search-bar" placeholder="search here..." >
    <label for="search-bar" class=" fas fa-search"></label>
</form>
```

## Css code is

@media(max-width:768px){

```
#menu-bar{
    display: initial;

}
header .navbar{
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;right:0;left:0px;
    background:beige;
    border-top: .1rem solid rgba(255,255,.2);
    padding:1rem 2rem;
    display:block;
    width:70%;
    transition:1s ease;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
}
header .navbar.active{
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

header .navbar a{
    display: block;
    border-radius:.5rem;
    padding:1.5rem;
    margin:1.5rem 0;
    background:crimson;
}
header .navbar a:hover{
background-color:rgba(232, 58, 107,.7);

}
header .navbar a:hover:after{
    display: none;
}
```

}

how to make this header be responsive. although i put media queries also.

Comment: Where exactly is your code for the hamburger menu? Are you sure this is the right code you've pasted?

Comment: Also, you've your css selectors messed up, I have fixed the selectors so the media query works, but still I cannot see the hamburger menu or anything like that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#menu-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.container-ring {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
  padding:0.5rem;
  margin:0.5rem 0.1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background:crimson;
}

.search-bar-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-bar-container input#search-bar {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  #menu-bar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .container-ring {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .search-bar-container {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-bar" class="fas fa-bars">
  <div class="container-ring">
      <div class="ring"></div>
      <div class="ring"></div>
      <div class="ring"></div>
      <a href="#" class="logo"><span>T</span>ravel</a>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="Tour.html">Tour</a>
    <a href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <form action="#" class="search-bar-container">
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fas fa-search" id="search-btn"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-user" id="login-btn"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="search" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search here..." >
      <label for="search-bar" class=" fas fa-search"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: But what's the media query if i want for desktop screen as well as mobile.

Comment: Could you maybe describe what you're trying to achieve? It'll give me a better idea of your problem and I will be able to help you better.

Comment: i want a responsive navigation bar for my project that works on every screen.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to code that yourself, unless you're just trying to learn how things work, because a framework like bootstrap would give that to you out of the box with minimum effort. At the same time, I have updated my answer, I hope it fits what you're looking for, although I am sure this can be done in many ways and you could tweak it further according to your liking.